# Merge inside the merge only if the first doesn't return a match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have 3 dataframes (df1, df2 & df3), the main one (df1) and two additional ones which contain 1 column amongst others that I want to bring over to the main dataframe.

Sample dfs:

```
df1 = {'Col_f': ['Georgia', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Arizona'],
          'Col_g': ['SUV', 'Coupe', 'Wagon', 'Crossover', 'Sedan']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2 = {'Col_g': ['SUV', '4x4', 'Wagon', 'Truck', 'Sedan'],
 'Objective': ['15%', '13%', '55%', '40.4%', '2.48%']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df3 = {'Col_f': ['Georgia', 'California', 'Pennsylvania', 'Texas', 'Arizona'],
 'Objective': ['15%', '13%', '55%', '40.4%', '2.48%']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
```

df1
[image]
df2
[image]

and df3
[image]

I am using the following code:

```
df1_new = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Col_g', how = 'left')

Which returns the following df:

df_new = {'Col_f': ['Georgia', 'California', 'Pennsylvania', 'Texas', 'Arizona'],
          'Col_g': ['SUV', 'Coupe', 'Wagon', 'Crossover', 'Sedan'],
         'Objective': ['15%', ' ', '55%', ' ', '2.48%']}
```

[image]

Then for the two empty strings for the "Objective" column I want to continue with a second merge (or an excel vlookup which I guess are the same), to fill in those empty ones.

Code that I thought would be used for the second merge:

```
df1_newer = pd.merge(df_new, df3, on = 'Col_f', how = 'left')
```

Desired final output.

```
df_newer = {'Col_f': ['Georgia', 'California', 'Pennsylvania', 'Texas', 'Arizona'],
          'Col_g': ['SUV', '4x4', 'Wagon', 'Truck', 'Sedan'],
         'Objective': ['15%', '13%', '55%', '40.4%', '2.48%']}
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be more than appreciated!

Comment: @Alexchristof20 I believe your example `df1` does not match your screenshots (second row).

Comment: @user2246849 Just fixed the screenshot, thanks for letting me know. I tried to oversimplify as much as possible so that it's easier to understand the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merging the three dataframes, you can use `mask` or `np.where` to conditionally assign value

```py
df1_new = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Col_g', how='left')['Objective']
df1_newer = pd.merge(df1, df3, on='Col_f', how='left')['Objective']
```

```
print(df1_new)

0      NaN
1      NaN
2      55%
3      NaN
4    2.48%
Name: Objective, dtype: object

print(df1_newer)

0      15%
1      NaN
2      NaN
3    40.4%
4    2.48%
Name: Objective, dtype: object
```

```py
df1['Objective'] = df1_new.mask(df1_new.isna(), df1_newer)

#or

import numpy as np

df1['Objective'] = np.where(df1_new.isna(), df1_newer, df1_new)
```

```
print(df1)

      Col_f      Col_g Objective
0   Georgia    Minivan       15%
1    Nevada      Coupe       NaN
2  New York      Wagon       55%
3     Texas  Crossover     40.4%
4   Arizona      Sedan     2.48%
```

Comment: I am in the process on giving even more information because after reading again my question it seems that it's a bit confusing. Thanks for your help though. I'll be updating it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Alexchristof20 this answer is correct if you apply it to the correct data (as I mentioned in the comment to the main post your `df1` doesn't match the screenshots).